# Braintree iOS SDK 4.0 - Reuse Add New Payment View Controller

Tags: ios, braintree

Is it possible to re-use the Braintree DropIn UI's Add New Payment View Controller? Or do we have to create a view controller manually from scratch and tokenize the new payment?

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

The screen that I am referring to:
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

I work at Braintree.

Either approach should work, but I think the best practice is to create it when it's necessary and deallocate it when you're done (i.e. do not keep a reference to it). Drop-in view controller instantiation is fairly lightweight, so instantiating it each time should not have much of an impact on CPU performance.

One small advantage of retaining the Drop-in view controller could be if you allow your customers to save payment methods to the Vault (e.g. your Braintree client token has a customer ID). In that case, the view controller loads saved payment methods from the Vault, which fires off a network call to load that data (see `BTDropInViewController -fetchPaymentMethodsOnCompletion`). Retaining the view controller in memory would allow you to cache the payment methods so that this doesn't have to be loaded.

The disadvantage to this approach is that you'd be keeping the view controller around in memory, which increases the memory footprint of your app. Also, the state of the Drop-in view controller will not be reset, so if your user partially fills out the card form, goes back, then returns at a later time, they'll still see the partially filled form.

Comment: Hey Richard. Thank you for the response, but it's not exactly the answer I was looking for. Perhaps I didn't phrase my question as well as I could have. What I want to do is isolate and only use this 'Add Payment Method' screen where users can vault their payment methods. They aren't going to be paying for anything in this instance, but just storing their details for later use. Can this be done through the Drop-in UI, or will I have to create a custom solution using Braintree provided UIs?

Comment: You can do this by creating the `BTPaymentRequest` and setting `shouldHideCallToAction` to `NO`.